# Server Not Listening Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm creating a project on express to make "Flask" in nodejs. But for some reason, it doesn't listen at all. In the console, it shows `listening on *:8080`, but the page doesn't show. Code:

index.js

```js
const { Flask, render_template } = require('./flask');
const app = Flask(__dirname);

app.route('/',()=>render_template('index.html'),);

app.run(8080,'0.0.0.0',(p,h)=>{
  console.log('\nlistening on *:'+p)
});
```

flask.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');

let request = {
  cookies: {
    get: (cookie)=>{},
    obj: {}
  },
  headers: {}
}

app.use((req,res)=>{
  const headers = req.headers;
  delete headers.host;
  delete headers['user-agent'];
  delete headers.accept;
  delete headers['accept-encoding'];
  delete headers['accept-language'];
  delete headers['if-none-match'];
  delete headers['referer'];
  delete headers['sec-ch-ua'];
  delete headers['sec-ch-ua-mobile'];
  delete headers['sec-ch-ua-platform'];
  delete headers['sec-fetch-dest'];
  delete headers['sec-fetch-mode'];
  delete headers['sec-fetch-site'];
  delete headers['sec-fetch-user'];
  delete headers['upgrade-insecure-requests'];
  delete headers['x-forwarded-for'];
  delete headers['x-forwarded-proto'];
  request.headers = headers;
});
function readdir(dirname, onFileContent, ) {
  fs.readdir(dirname,function(err, filenames) {
    onFileContent(filenames);
  });
};
function isDir(path) {
  try {
    var stat = fs.lstatSync(path);
    return stat.isDirectory();
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
app.use(require('cookie-parser')())
if(fs.existsSync('static')){
  app.use(express.static('static'))
};

app.use((req,res,next)=>{
  let entr = Object.entries(req.cookies);
  for(var i=0;i<entr.length;i++){
    if(typeof(entr[i][1])=='object'){
      entr[i][1] = JSON.stringify(entr[i][1]);
    }
    request.cookies.obj[entr[i][0]] = entr[i][1];
  }
});

function setErrorStatus(code, callback){
  if(!file){
    app.use((err,req,res,next)=>{
      const status = res.statusCode;
      res.status(status==200?500:code);
      callback({
        redirect: (loc)=>{res.redirect(loc);next()},
        send_file: (fileName)=>{res.sendFile(fileName);next()}
      });
    });
  };
}

function route(dir,call,method="GET"){
  if(method == 'GET'){
    app.get(dir,(req,res)=>{
      res.send(call());
    });
  } else if (method == 'POST'){
    app.post(dir,(req,res)=>{
      res.send(call());
    });
  } else if (method == 'ALL'){
    app.all(dir,(req,res)=>{
      res.send(call());
    });
  } else {
    app.get(dir,(req,res)=>{
      res.send(call())
    })
  }
};

function render_template(file){
  try{
    return fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/templates/'+file,'utf8')
  } catch (e) {
    let htii;
    console.error(`Error: ENOENT\nNo file/dir called "templates/${file}.`);
    process.exit(73);
  }
}

function run(port=8080,host='0.0.0.0',callback=()=>{}){
  app.listen(port,host='0.0.0.0');
  return callback(port, host);
}

function flask(){
  return {
    route: route,
    run: run,
    // on: appon
  }
}

function send_file(
fileName_or_fp,
as_download = false
){
  if(res == null){ return; };
  if(as_download){
    res.download(fileName_or_fp);
  } else {
    res.render(fileName_or_fp);
  }
}
module.exports = {
  Flask: flask,
  render_template: render_template,
  request: request
}
```

templates/index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Flask Loaded!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I load it for the first time, it shows a blank page, even though it *should* show the `/templates/index.html` file after loading.

What I Tried:

- uninstalling and reinstalling express and cookie-parser
- tested express on `index.js`
- made a duplicate of that same project .

Please help.

***Note*: This is not a duplicate of another question.**

Comment: No (uncaught) errors in your output? I'm pretty sure your `app.run` callback is always called, since you don't pass an error-handling callback to (Express's) `app.listen`.

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs No errors, and I think it's probably `app.route`'s problem, since `app.listen` looks completely fine

Comment: I do notice you adding that `app.get('/', ...)` **every** time, and twice for your test server, but I _think_ Express should be able to handle that?

Comment: I was doing that to test the server, and I forgot to remove it when I copy-pasted the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation on middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html), your middleware gets passed a third argument, a `next` function you should call to pass the request to the next middleware or final route handler. For example:

```js
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Time:', Date.now())
  next()
})
```

In your first `app.use` where you delete those headers, you don't accept that argument, therefore Express stops doing anything after your middleware, including not sending a response.

Comment: Seems like that cookies middleware isn't calling `next()` either.

Comment: I tried removing cookie-parser, but still not working either :\

Comment: I meant your custom `app.use` a few lines lower where you iterate over `req.cookies` and such, not the `require('cookie-parser')()` one.